# What is the origin of the British phrase "Rough as houses"?

Tags: etymology, british-english, phrase-origin

I'm preempting the usual comments by saying: If you're not British, you *probably* won't have heard it before.

But it is a fairly well known phrase in BrE.

For instance, in [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PlPjFEp0h3AC&pg=PT166&dq=%22rough%20as%20houses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif15Gmkrr0AhUMJ8AKHTxLAmsQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=%22rough%20as%20houses%22&f=false):

> Unfortunately, it meant that we were without Yos and Ga for the game and myself, Jer, Jumpy, Sherry, Reg, Pob, were all feeling distinctly *rough as houses.*
>
> Pretty much the last thing you want to do with a stinking hangover is go out on a Sunday morning, put shorts on and attempt to run around in the pouring and freezing rain.

<sub>emphasis added</sub>

Which matches my understanding of it meaning "feeling very unwell".

Even though [nGrams finds nothing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Rough+as+houses&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3), I'm confident it's not a new phrase.

The [answer bank](https://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Phrases-and-Sayings/Question94911.html) has some speculative guesses (derived from "roughhousing" or "rough as a bag/arsehole"), but I'm looking for an actual etymology and/or origin.

What is the origin of the British phrase "Rough as houses" ?

Comment: *"If you're not American, you probably won't have heard it before."*  Isn't this the opposite of what you are trying to say?

Comment: @daniel, I got my muddle in a words it seems.

Comment: I speak BE: it is quite rare. However... http://www.word-detective.com/2011/10/roughhousing/: *"A “rough house” in 19th century Britain was an inn, pub or private home known as a “rough” place where brawls regularly broke out (“The defendant had been drinking at the new Inn for three weeks … Mr. Oglethorpe stated that it was a rough house … The prisoner had been convicted frequently for assaults on the police,” 1874). So “to roughhouse” was originally to behave as if you were a habitué of a seedy and violent dive.*" I suggest that "rough as houses" comes from this source.

Comment: Is "safe as houses" meant to be taken ironically?

Comment: @Greybeard But the term here is NOT rough house. rough as houses could easily come from to roughhouse, too.

Comment: @Lambie: my suggestion is that "rough as houses" = "rough as roughhouses" in which the second "rough" is lost for effect.

Comment: It only seems to show up in books after 2000 according to google. I noted that "rough as toast" has a lot of traction and is used in the context of hangovers/feeling poorly as well as just a general exclamation of bad workmanship etc. Some claim it as Scotland regional (?)

Comment: @Yorik I definitely heard it growing up, and I grew in the 90s ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of joke: **To roughhouse is a verb**; here, he is hung over so he says "rough as houses", which is just silly and mimics his quasi-drunk state. It's a bad joke.

Not to be confused with a "rough house", which would be a bar with brawlers or petty criminals. And, fyi, it is not fairly common at all. And is not particularly BrE.

**Merriam Webster**:

roughhouse

2 of 2
verb
rough·​house ˈrəf-ˌhau̇s  -ˌhau̇z
roughhoused; roughhousing
transitive verb

: to treat in a boisterously rough manner
intransitive verb

: to engage in roughhouse

**Cambridge Dictionary**

to fight in a way that is not serious:
A couple of boys were roughhousing (each other) in the park.

Comment: Do you have a source for that connection?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Some questions are not in sources. Ever heard of creative writing? Here in reference to being drunk.